# Importing a firebase collection into BigQuery using fs-bq-import-collection fails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have installed the new BigQuery export firebase extension on my firestore database and it works great.

Now I am trying to import the existing data in the collection by following the instructions on the extension but getting the error below.

https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md

**Any ideas how to resolve this error?**

Note: I ran `gcloud components update` to update to the latest gcloud versions

```
npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection
```

```
Importing data from Cloud Firestore Collection: members, to BigQuery Dataset: qmtbc_dev_export, Table: members_raw_changelog
Error unlinking journal file C:\Users\fullo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10884\node_modules\@firebaseextensions\fs-bq-import-collection\lib/from-members-to-qmtbc-dev:qmtbc_dev_export:members_raw_changelog
after successful import: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'C:\Users\fullo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10884\node_modules\@firebaseextensions\fs-bq-import-collection\lib\from-members-to-qmtbc-dev:qmtbc_dev_export:members_raw_changelog'
---------------------------------------------------------
Finished importing 0 Firestore rows to BigQuery
---------------------------------------------------------
Error importing Collection to BigQuery: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\fullo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10884\node_modules\@firebaseextensions\fs-bq-import-collection\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
```

**Update 1:**

I have been stuck on this for over 24hrs now.
I have reinstalled nodejs to v12.13 and killed my virus checker, rebooted etc
No luck.
Also tried npm rebuild

The closest issues I have seen are:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2464#issuecomment-325497850
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2464#issuecomment-328853460

**Update 2:**

I have uninstalled node and tried versions 8.16.2, 10.17 and 12.13
I deleted my npm and npm cache folders and reinstalled my global node packages.
Still no luck.  I may try this method instead: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore

**Update 3:**

I have given up.  It would be good to know if this script actually works for others.

Comment: Also raised an issue in githib: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/80

Comment: Getting this as well - repro'd on two different OSX machines (14.1.2).  Node v18.19.0.

However, it also doesn't seem to matter.  My data is getting copied just fine.  I just had to use the right syntax to get a a nested collection with group queries.

Comment: Sorry for the digging, but i have the exact same error and nothing helped me. I use a service account with bigquery Admin rights and still have the same issue. Did someone solved it ?

Comment: @Aion I never came back to this so no solution from me.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. You just need to go to the IAM page in the Google Cloud Platform dashboard and give the user enough rights. Add a role with enough permissions to create a BigQuery datasets.

Comment: FWIW adding BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Job User, BigQuery User, BigQuery Admin, and a few others did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

you have to export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json file first and then issue npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-import-collection command